# Image folding by dividing into grid for convolutional neural network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Suppose I have a 300 x 300 input image with 1 channel, contained in a numpy array with shape (300, 300, 1). And the channel is single bit - either 0 or 1.

How can I divide it into a 4 x 4 grid, each grid being 75 by 75 pixels wide and stack the grids together by summing up the bits?

In the end, I'd have a single numpy array that's (75, 75, 1). The value of the last channel can range from 0 to 16 at this point.

How well would this work as an input to a convolutional neural network? Is this an effective way of shrinking my input?

Comment: Any reason why you can't slice the original array into smaller ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html

```py
#mocking a single channel binary image
SIZE = 300
X = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=(SIZE,SIZE,1))

BLOCK_SIZE = 4
assert SIZE % BLOCK_SIZE == 0
# defining the moving window by its strides
new_stride = [X.strides[0], X.strides[1], X.strides[0]*BLOCK_SIZE, X.strides[1]*BLOCK_SIZE, X.strides[2]]
coarsened_X = np.sum( np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, shape=[BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE, SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE, 1], strides=new_stride), axis=(0,1))
```

About your final question: yeah I do think it's a relevant way of shrinking the input of your CNN, depending on how much training data you have available it can be more efficient that a first trainable convolutional layer on a very large image. Note that it's preferable to average your inputs instead of summing them for optimization purposes.

A benchmark showing it's ~50x times faster for an array of your size:

[image]

edit:

I just tried this method of doing it using only reshape and orient transform, possibly less readable and/or generalizable:

```py
X.reshape(BLOCK_SIZE, SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE, SIZE//BLOCK_SIZE, 1, order='F').sum(axis=(0,2))
```

I am suggesting it as it seems to be a few percent faster than the stride way. Just in case of interest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested methods! This was super helpful.

Comment: To average my inputs, I could divide the whole numpy array by 16
arr = arr / 16.0. When you say that it's preferable for optimization purposes, you mean during the training/fitting phase right? As in, having my inputs strictly range between 0 and 1.

Comment: I meant that (relatively) high input values can cause vanishing or exploding gradients, which may break the learning. Any scaling done on the training data needs to be repeated on the data inferred on. And yeah / 16 is the transform I suggest here. X -> (X-8)/16 could do too, as well as other ways.